# vim select and copy text between two files

Tags: vim, vi

I have the following scenario, two open files with

```
vim -O2 file1.txt file2.txt
```

My cursor is in file1.txt. I want to select some lines (say from line 80 to 100)
in file2.txt but without having to move my cursor to file2.txt and yank there the 
text. And if possible using the command line of vim. Do you have any suggestion?

thanks.

Comment: FYI, the `2` in `-O2` is not needed.

Answer (score 5):

The closest I can think of is:

```
:bn|80,100y|bp|pu
```

- switch to the next buffer
- yank
- switch back
- put yanked stuff

Comment: this is the easiest way I think from all the comments.

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
:call setline(80, getbufline(bufnr('file2.txt'), 80, 100))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have something like `sed` installed, another possibility is:

```
:r!sed -n '80,100p' file2.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for `diffput`?

```
vimdiff file1.txt file2.txt
:80,100diffput
```